# How to get if User pressed Enter wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to get the Input from a field

```cpp
wxTextCtrl* upperOnly = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Test"),wxPoint(5,260), wxSize(630,30));
```

and this i want every Time the user Pressed Enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER` when creating the control, i.e.

```
wxTextCtrl* upperOnly = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Test"),wxPoint(5,260), wxSize(630,30), wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER);
```

Then catch `wxEVT_TEXT_ENTER` and do your validation in its event handler, i.e.

```
upperOnly->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT_ENTER, [](wxCommandEvent&) {
        // Do something useful
     });
```